# Joining polygons touching and merging in one

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I am working in QGIS, doing research in different types of forest reserves. I've got this layer of reserves which are for some reason divided into a lot of small polygons (image below).

I want to merge polygons in 6 islands, by selecting polygons in each island that are touching each other. So as you can see in image below the result should be only 6 polygons, instead of these islands consisting from many polygons.

Is there any simple solution to this? I know how to do this manually by selecting and merging them but there are around 4000 polygons, so...

[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Research Dissolve

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I'd like to ask a question here in the comments. Maybe @Vince or someone else here could help me understand something, please? Is it against the rules to ask such rookie-level questions? Since it's not the first time I've seen them downvoted.

Comment: @user99006 Questions like this belong in [meta]. It's not "against the rules" to ask basic Questiions, though it might strike some as not being sufficiently researched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Vince. I'll go check the GIS Meta.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Dissolve.

Make sure you dissolve without selecting any of the fields. After the dissolve you have to do a Multipart to Singleparts to divide the parks

Comment: It would be better to dissolve by ReserveCode, so that all attributes are not lost, and Multipart To Singlepart isn't going to work with the reserve to the northeast.

Comment: Yes, as @Vince said the attributes are lost, thank you nonetheless. how do you use ReserveCode?